# Placing html tag inside string

Tags: javascript, reactjs

It seems to be easy, but for some reason I cannot do it.

In React I have an object:

```
const test = {
  paragraphs: [
    'text of paragraph A text <a>link</a> text', //<a> tag will be printed just as a string
    'text of paragraph B text text',
  ]
}
```

I'm mapping paragraphs in order to get few paragraphs rendered, like so.

```
test.paragraphs.map(item => <p>item</p>)
```

All works just fine. But what if I want to put a link tag inside the first paragraph. How can I embed html tag inside of the first string in the array?

Comment: Is the `<` key on your keyboard broken or something? (You should provide a [mcve] and a clear problem statement)

Comment: Does your link have a specific format?

Comment: @kemicofa nope, it is typical

Comment: Share the code. How you are rendering these paragraphs ? I don't see any html code inside these paragraphs

Comment: I updated my question guys

Comment: Will the tag always be an `<a>`, or can you get something else (like a `br`) ?

Comment: [Checkout this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57955460/insert-html-tags-inside-the-jsx-object-for-mapping/57955523?noredirect=1#57955568) similar question and answer provided

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of how to convert your string to HTML in an reactjs application

```
class App extends React.Component {

constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      description: '<a href={to} target="_blank" {...rest}>{children}</a>'
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.state.description }} />
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 0):

React don't transform your string automatically to JSX element, it's renderer as is.

So React allow your to inject your html code inside a HTML component with dangerouslySetInnerHTML props. At your own risk :)

See the docs [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml)

```
render() {
    return (
        <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: '<p>This is dangerous</p>' }} />
    );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use [String#replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace). A basic regex to find urls and then use a callback to wrap the link in an `<a>`

```js
const test = {
  paragraphs: [
    'text of paragraph A text http://google.com',
    'text of paragraph B text text',
    'text of paragraph http://www.yahoo.com B text text',
    'text http://google.com of paragraph http://www.yahoo.com B text text',
  ]
};

const res = test.paragraphs.map(p=>{
   return `<p>${p.replace(/http(s)?\:\/\/(www.)?[a-zA-Z]+\.[a-z]+/g, (link)=>`<a href="${link}">${link}</a>`)}</p>`;
   
});

document.body.innerHTML = res.join("");
```